# Checkbox validated as "on" when form is submitted unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form here: http://www.problemio.com/test.php when you click on the "Click To Test Signup"

If you just submit the form without filling it out, the JS validation realizes that all the fields are empty, except for the checkbox at the bottom.  It says that the checkbox is on even if it is unchecked.

Any idea why that happens? And what is the right way to validate the checkbox there?

```
    var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions").val();
```

and this line outputs it as :on" alert ("Data string " + dataString);

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you paste in the javascript your using for the validation?

Comment: @Chris just added some code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead to get the right value.

```
$("#terms_and_conditions").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to test like this (using the [:checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)):

```
var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions:checked").val();
```

or, better, use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions").prop('checked');
```

this is because the value on a checkbox is always set - the only thing that changes is the checked-state so this is what you really have to test.

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions").prop("checked");
```

that should return a boolean depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$("#terms_and_conditions:checked").val();
```

you either get the `val()` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from this:

```
var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions").val();
```

to this:

```
var terms_and_conditions = $("#terms_and_conditions").is(":checked");
```